# Need a solution for Live GPS Tracking Visualization and Communication

Tags: gps, visualization, tracking

Suppose there is an individual out in the fields, and he has an android phone with him. The phone is equipped with GPS. I'd like the GPS data to be transmitted to my PC and visualized in Google Earth in real time. I'd like to be able to talk to the subject on the phone at the same time, to guide him / her through the terrain.

Is there already such an app available? If not I'll create my own.

Thank you very much for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

[RealtimeTracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greenalp.RealtimeTracker&hl=nl) looks promising or [latify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ecs.latify) for google latitude or [MapTrack](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vistechprojects.maptrack)... A [quick search at the play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=real%20time%20location%20sharing&c=apps) can get you a long way...